# swiper slider, предупреждение из за loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Установил swiper slider через npm и все хорошо работает но, в консоле предупреждение **"Swiper Loop Warning: The number of slides is not enough for loop mode, it will be disabled and not function properly. You need to add more slides (or make duplicates) or lower the values of slidesPerView and slidesPerGroup parameters"**. Если убрать loop: true то это предупреждение уходит. Есть какое то разумное решение? заранее спасибо.

```
const swiper1 = new Swiper('.team-swiper', {
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

**html:**

```
<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="team-swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Предупреждение закиньте в переводчик. Там же написано: _"You need to add more slides (or make duplicates) or lower the values of slidesPerView and slidesPerGroup parameters"_

Comment: Да в том то и прикол что ничего не помагает, даже через chatgpt не могу сделать. Пишет что нужно более 2х слайдов но их тут 3.